# некорректное отображение svg маркера в Яндекс картах в браузере FireFox и IE

Tags: javascript, svg, yandex-maps-api, firefox

Некорректное отображение svg маркера в Яндекс картах в браузере FireFox и IE.
В браузере firefox изображение растягивает, в IE в границах блока маркера изображение заливается как будто background-repeat: repeat;

https://codepen.io/anticipant_sh/pen/vrMoaP

```
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
            zoom: 9
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),

        // Создаём макет содержимого.
        MyIconContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
            '<div style="color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold;">$[properties.iconContent]</div>'
        ),

        myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
            hintContent: 'Собственный значок метки',
            balloonContent: 'Это красивая метка'
        }, {
            // Опции.
            // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
            iconLayout: 'default#image',
            // Своё изображение иконки метки.
            // iconImageHref: 'images/myIcon.gif',
            iconImageHref: 'https://7745.by/images/map/map-marker2.svg',

            // Размеры метки.
            iconImageSize: [30, 42],
            // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
            // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
            iconImageOffset: [-5, -38]
        }),

        myPlacemarkWithContent = new ymaps.Placemark([55.661574, 37.573856], {
            hintContent: 'Собственный значок метки с контентом',
            balloonContent: 'А эта — новогодняя',
            iconContent: '12'
        }, {
            // Опции.
            // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
            iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
            // Своё изображение иконки метки.
            iconImageHref: 'images/ball.png',
            // Размеры метки.
            iconImageSize: [48, 48],
            // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
            // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
            iconImageOffset: [-24, -24],
            // Смещение слоя с содержимым относительно слоя с картинкой.
            iconContentOffset: [15, 15],
            // Макет содержимого.
            iconContentLayout: MyIconContentLayout
        });

    myMap.geoObjects
        .add(myPlacemark)
        .add(myPlacemarkWithContent);
});
```

есть ли варианты решения этой проблемы или единственный вариант через png делать?

Comment: Для того, чтобы починить сразу во всех браузерах нужно использовать png. Если вы готовы забить на IE, то можно задать размеры метки так чтобы метка принимала правильную форму в FF. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LrorBK

Answer (score 1):

Нужно подогнать размер svg под размер метки, т.к. в IE яндекс-карты по какой-то причине не задают `background-size`.  Код иконки:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 9.831 14.782" width="30" height="42">
 <path fill="#696969" d="M9.831 4.916c0 2.714-3.538 8.487-4.913 9.867C3.437 13.307 0 7.631 0 4.916S2.201 0 4.916 0s4.915 2.201 4.915 4.916z"/>
 <circle cx="4.912" cy="4.916" r="2.932" fill="#FEFEFE"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"  можно не указывать, так как это значение по умолчанию.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT , согласен, был не прав. Ответ отредактировал.